# waitlist behaviour

Tags: waitlist

I'm wanting to keep track of event attendance and in particular to distinguish between those who let us know at the last minute from the complete no-shows. With earlier cancellations I can use the "cancelled" status, which will trigger an offer on the wait-list, but I'm concerned that if I set someone to "cancelled" after the event that it will still offer a place to someone on the wait-list which would be wrong. I can't see anything that stops registration after the date of the event and I presume that this means the wait-list would behave the same.

It would be good to know the default behavior before I explore a few work rounds. I can see a few ways round this:

a) set the online registration to explicitly stop on the day of the event (but would still need to check this would apply to the wait-list

b) explicitly disable the event booking before recording the attenance information

c) creating a new status of "Apologised" for late cancellations that is still counted in the attendance count.

Comment: This maybe the sort of conundrum that is best analysed by creating a test event and seeing what happens

Comment: Certainly am considering that but involves doing things over a few days to let the event date pass and the wait-list processing run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realised that I didn't have to wait for the participant status cron job to run and could run it from the console, so have done some testing and find that by default a cancellation after the event means that a wait-listed person will be offered a place to a now past event. So I looked at my alternatives.

a) does work and is probably the safest and sensibly matches any cut off time for event bookings.

b) works, but I think the person managing the event may forgot

c) works and I thinks its probably what I will use as it distinguishes between the two cases where the place can potentially be reused or not.

Comment: Glad you found something that can work for you. Still sounds as if the Waitlist feature could do with a tweak to avoid functioning after Event End Date - if you are keen you could open an issue in https://lab.civicrm.org/dev

Comment: I think its probably OK, because the waitlist processing only happens when the online booking is open. Its easy to set a cut-off date for bookings. Whilst I can't see a reason for allowing online bookings after the event date, I guess it might allow flexibility for some unusually usage.

Comment: Bearing in mind the previous comment I actually chose to use my option (a) above.